# Season Ranking System XP Requirements

Tags: halo-reach, halo-the-master-chief-collection

I bought Halo MCC on Steam and I started playing multiplayer. How many points do we need to get the highest rank (prestige) Tier 1?

According to the wiki here is all progression ranks :

[image]

I'm not talking about this Rank system that only concerns Ranked game :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

According to a user [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/halo/comments/e6esxe/there_is_prestiges_in_halo_reach/), it takes around 1.95 Million EXP to prestige, as there are 10 full tiers, it will probably be around 19.5-20 million total EXP to get to the Tier 1 final rank.

I can't find the source currently but I remember reading that 343i said it would take efficient users around 4 months to get to max rank so this does seem around the correct pace.

Comment: I will wait for an official announcement or I will wait for a player to reach the Tier 1 final rank. If your answer is correct I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently at Tier 5 Captain. I have over 82 million points. The ranks certainly get exponentially higher to gain an increase in rank. I needed over 2 million points just to go from Captain Tier 5 (my current rank), to Major Tier 5. At this rate, I would say Tier 1 is at least 200 Million Points, but probably more like half a billion.